# Cannot create object when creating user-defined copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants, copy-constructor

This code worked before trying to add a copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Laptop
{
    public:
        string brand;
        string model;
        int ram;
        int storage;

        Laptop(string brand, string model, int ram, int storage)
        {
            this->brand = brand;
            this->model = model;
            this->ram = ram;
            this->storage = storage;
        }
        Laptop(Laptop &x)
        {
            this->brand = x.brand;
            this->model = x.model;
            this->ram = x.ram;
            this->storage = x.storage;
        }
        void displayData()
        {
            cout << brand << " " << model << ": RAM = " << ram << "GB, Storage = " << storage << "GB" << endl;        
        }
};

int main()
{
    Laptop myLaptop = Laptop("Asus", "Zenbook", 16, 2048);
    Laptop copyOriginal = Laptop(myLaptop);

    copyOriginal.displayData();

    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not work, it only works when I create `myLaptop` and `oldLaptop` using this syntax:

```
Laptop myLaptop("Asus", "Zenbook", 16, 2048);
Laptop copyOriginal(myLaptop);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not bind a non-constant reference to a temporary object and for example in this declaration the right side is a temporary object

```
Laptop myLaptop = Laptop("Asus", "Zenbook", 16, 2048);
```

Declare the copy like

```
    Laptop( const Laptop &x)
    {
        this->brand = x.brand;
        this->model = x.model;
        this->ram = x.ram;
        this->storage = x.storage;
    }
```

Or add the move constructor.

Take into account that you need to include the header `<string>` not the header `<string.h>`.

```
#include <string>
```

Your class can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class Laptop
{
    public:
        string brand;
        string model;
        int ram;
        int storage;

        Laptop( const string &brand, const string &model, int ram, int storage)
            : brand( brand ), model( model ), ram( ram ), storage( storage )
        {
        }


        Laptop( const Laptop &x)
            : brand( x.brand ), model( x.model ), ram( x.ram ), storage( x.storage )
        {
        }

        Laptop( Laptop &&x)
            : brand( std::move( x.brand ) ), model( std::move( x.model ) ), ram( x.ram ), storage( x.storage )
        {
        }

        void displayData() const
        {
            cout << brand << " " << model << ": RAM = " << ram << "GB, Storage = " << storage << "GB" << endl;        
        }
};
//...
```

Comment: What does the ```const``` mean here?

Comment: @MayarKarout Means a constant reference. You may not bind a non-constant reference to a temporary object.